# Converting image taken from camera to canvas has gray on the side

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, mobile-safari

Im using vanilla javascript to capture images from the camera and into the canvas.  Its working fine on Chrome Android but not in iOS Safari.  As seen in the screenshot, there is a gray area on the image.  Is there something I need to do to not get that rendered?

**JavaScript for the camera**

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    'audio': false,
    'video': {
        facingMode: 'environment'
    }
}).then(stream => {
    this.VIDEO.srcObject = stream;
    this.VIDEO.addEventListener('loadeddata', async () => {
        this.VIDEO.width = this.VIDEO.videoWidth;
        this.VIDEO.height = this.VIDEO.videoHeight;
        this.CANVAS.width = this.VIDEO.videoWidth;
        this.CANVAS.height = this.VIDEO.videoHeight;
        resolve();
    }, false);
}).catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
    self.MESSAGE.textContent = error;
});
```

**JavaScript for drawing on the canvas and the preview window**

```
self.CONTEXT.drawImage(self.VIDEO, 0, 0, self.VIDEO.width, self.VIDEO.height);

let imgDataURL = self.CANVAS.toDataURL('image/png');
self.PLANT.src = imgDataURL;
self.POLAROID.style.backgroundImage = `url(${imgDataURL})`;
```

[image]

Comment: I guess this relates to the image ratio and how the image is handled as CSS background image. When the original image is in portrait format and your ``POLAROID`` element has a quadratic shape then the image gets fitted by its height and the background of your element shines through. Maybe set a different CSS ``background-size`` property (cover or contain).

Comment: No ios safari to test, but can you confirm this fiddle also renders the gray part? https://jsfiddle.net/26awedft/

Comment: @tomacco, the POLAROID element is already in cover property.

Comment: @Kaiido, apologies as I can test that codepen.  I too dont have an iOS device and rely on my colleagues phone.  The border is just CSS.  The gray area is not.  ITs part of the conversion

Comment: @oninross Is the whole image rendered in the ``POLAROID`` element or is it cut off? What happens when you change ``POLAROID``'s ``background-color`` or ``background-position`` properties? When your camera's image ratio does not match ``POLAROID`` element's ratio then there is always a border when you want to show the whole image. BTW What happens on Chrome? Is the image stretched or zoomed in?

Comment: That's unfortunate... It would be helpful to know from where it comes, and someone being able to reproduce is the minimum to find it... So lets assume it indeed already on the canvas, that would mean it is already like this on the video and on the MediaStream, i.e Safari's young implementation wouldn't go by the standards and would apply some silly aspect-ratio constraints on the videoTrack... Not sure how it should be detected though, but one thing to look at is the `aspectRatio` MediaContraint.

Comment: @tomacco silly me, it is actually the background of the POLAROID element.  So the issue is actually now why is it not occupying the entire width of the container?  In Android Chrome it works fine.  Just iOS Safari that is being a pain

Comment: @tomacco, all good now.  looks great on iOS devices.  Thanks for your effort and help.  Must be caching or something.